# jQuery and Drupal behavior issue on document.ready

Tags: php, jquery, drupal

I have an odd problem in my jQuery code that loads in Drupal **7**. I used the following instruction :

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: myPopUpFunction.....

})(jQuery);
```

On my mac browsers this codes loads after the document is loaded however on PC the popUp loads  first and then the whole page loads.

Any idea?

Thank you,

Comment: So which is correct, displaying first or displaying after?

Comment: sorry. I would like to have it loaded after the page load.

Comment: @arashaga when you mean mac browsers does it merely refer to Safari on Mac??

Comment: I mean both safari and firefox on mac respond to it differently> On PC I tested with Firefox and IE and the pop-up loads first and after dismissing the pop-up window the hole page loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure if your issue is browser specific, but my suggestion is that you could bind the `myPopUpFunction` with the window's load event, in that way only after the window's elements are all loaded the popup method would be triggered invoking the popup load

```
$(window).bind('load', function() {
// popup load goes here
});
```

this should serve the cause, but the popup would load after **'all'** the elements including images which might not be desired.

Note: jQuery 1.7 onward suggests method .[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead of bind.